# How to overflow in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if I should be using `overflow` or something else to fix this, but would appreciate any help I could get.

Scroll to the very bottom of the page.  You will see at the very bottom where there's the black div and right below that is a little white space.

How can make that white space become black and still keep the rounded corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set bottom padding of `.s-inn-mid` to 0
2. Add bottom left and right border-radius 5px to the black div.
   `border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px`

I'd tell you it exactly in terms of classes and ids, but you are using inline styles (GROSS), so that's unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your padding-bottom to 0, and set the border radius bottom to the right and the left of the s-in-mid div.

Comment: nice copypasta from my answer, nice job.

Comment: oh my goodness, I am so so so sorry if you think so.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.s-inn-mid {
  padding: 7px 0px 6px 0px;
  ...
```

to this:

```
.s-inn-mid {
  padding: 7px 0px 0px 0px;
  ...
```

FYI, this has nothing to do with `overflow`. You simply had padding on the bottom of your container div.

Answer (score -1):

in signup.css line 293 change #fff to #000, as below, tested in chrome.

```
.s-inn-mid {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 0px 6px 0px;
float: left;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;  
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: that has undesired side effect of all the header going black.

Comment: looks fine in my browser!